# Get template roles (REST API)

Tags: docusignapi

I'm interested in getting roles from templates to populate them correctly and keep that up to date automatically.

Is it somehow possible to get that using REST API?

There's the "Get Account Template by ID - v2/accounts/:accountId/templates/:templateId" request but it seems to return little useful info regarding roles or recipients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the REST API, you can get recipient Role Names for a Template by simply executing a "GET Envelope Recipients" request, where you specify the **Template Id** in place of the **Envelope Id**.  For example:

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{templateId}/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=true

The response to this request will contain an array of recipient objects for each recipient type (i.e.: signers, agents, editors, intermediaries, carbonCopies, certifiedDeliveries, inPersonSigners); each recipient object will contain the property **roleName**. Here's an example response for a template that contains 3 recipients -- 2 signers and one CC recipient:

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "recipientId": "5741ec70-b056-44eb-b462-eceee88ddf77",
            "requireSignerCertificate": "false",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "Signer 1",
            "status": "created",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        },
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "recipientId": "c64d4567-2efd-422d-9b0a-a5427aa2512d",
            "requireSignerCertificate": "false",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "roleName": "Signer 2",
            "status": "created",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [
        {
            "name": "Legal Team",
            "email": "email3@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "a63e3714-adc2-4e05-b2c5-b3c3bbf50aa2",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "3",
            "roleName": "Legal Team",
            "status": "created",
            "templateLocked": "true",
            "templateRequired": "true"
        }
    ],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "3"
}
```

Comment: @KimBrandl is there any way to get recipient data for a list of templates in the API, or do i have to call each template individually?

Comment: With the REST API, you have to request recipient data for each template individually. However, I believe with the "RequestTemplateList" operation of the SOAP API, you can request data about multiple Templates in a single API request.  See "RequestTemplateList" operation info starting on p213 of the SOAP API guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @KimBrandl, i'll just put up with individual rest requests :)